# Pandas dataframe error with lambda function when applied on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Pandas is throwing an error stating that float object is not subscriptable.Although I used that code above and it worked fine. I really don't know why it is happening. How can pandas be so inconsistent? This is when I tried to see how lambda is interpreting this.[image: this shows error I am getting when I want to extract let's say 0th element from the row of list]

Comment: Some of the data might be missing (`np.nan`) and was treated as `float`?

Comment: Thank you Quang! I just figured out that 50 rows had np.nan values. But I really appreciate your quick reponse!